# Find Function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, find, visual-studio-macros, vba

I want to search for all Dates belonging to a month. The Month will be selected by the user.
I am unable to search all dates, I only get the last date which is entered. I am using find function and unable to provide the specific conditions.

```
    mois = InputBox("Choisissez le mois (Entrer la valeur Numérique)!!! (1 pour Janvier, 2 pour Fév .... )", "Titre")
   If mois > 0 & mois < 12 Then
    ' Search for matching date
    Set cellsearch = Range("G1:G" & NbrLinesDate).Find(What:=mois_chercher)

    If cellsearch Is Nothing Then
        If mois < 0 Then
        ElseIf mois > 12 Then
        End If
    Else
    ligne = cellsearch.Row
    Date_to_search = Range("G" & ligne).Value
End If
End If
    MsgBox Date_to_search                           '' Checkpoint_1
    JourTest = Day(Date_to_search)
    JourTest = Trim(JourTest)
    MsgBox JourTest                                 '' Checkpoint_2
```

Mois is the variable, that stores user provided month value.
In this code, I am not using this variable mois for searching dates which belongs to this month.
I am unable to achieve that.

```
Date_de_Survenance
 30/01/2013
 31/01/2013
 31/01/2013
 04/02/2013
 05/02/2013
 07/02/2013
 11/02/2013
 13/02/2013
 13/02/2013
 13/02/2013
 15/02/2013
 20/02/2013
```

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: May I see your exact code?

Comment: Done. I have finished editing.

Comment: But you have specified the complete parameters. Please see the link that I have given above

Comment: The search is not going beyond the 12th cell(Row wise). It is not searching according to Month, but according to cell number.
I want it to search all dates which are in FEB for ex: 04/02/2013, 05/02/2013, when I enter 2 in inputbox.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Do not use .Find for that. Take the input and then use Autofilter for that. Let me give you an example

Comment: how does Auto_filter accepts date ranges..?

Comment: Updating my answer. One moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example. I am not using the `Inputbox` for taking input but rather using a hard coded value for demonstration purpose.

Lets say your Excel data looks like this.

[image]

Simply paste this code in a module and run it.

**Code**

```
'
' Excel Constants for Months for Autofilter
'
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJanuary = 21
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodFebruray = 22
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodMarch = 23
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodApril = 24
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodMay = 25
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJune = 26
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodJuly = 27
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodAugust = 28
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodSeptember = 29
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodOctober = 30
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodNovember = 31
'   xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodDecember = 32


Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lMnth As Long, constmonth As Long

    '~~> Feb
    lMnth = 2
    constmonth = lMnth + 20 '~~> (See the commented section for constants)

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            constmonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Where is the variable rng As Range being used...?

Comment: Ah! Ignore that. i was planning on storing `.Range("A1:A" & lRow)` in that. I will amend the above post

Comment: I have one more query. How can I use value of variable defined in a sub to another sub defined in another module. For Ex: Module1 contains Sub1 which contains variable x=3, I want to use this value of x in Module1 which contains Sub2.